# Iota java api unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ssl-certificate, payara, iota

I'm using the `java wrapper` for iota [iota-java](https://github.com/iotaledger/iota-java).
I have a java ee application (payara) where I connect to the following url
[nodes](https://nodes.thetangle.org:443).

However when trying to get some information from the tangle, for example `bundlesFromAddresses` I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
 sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I read some other answers and I came to the conclusion that my own payara domain does not trust the certificate of [nodes](https://nodes.thetangle.org:443).

However I dont understand what and why this is happening. Is it a problem with my configuration or is the error somewhere else?